# Usage of articles for countable nouns

Tags: grammar

The sentence is:

> I don't enjoy watching horror movies.

Why not use:

> I don't enjoy watching a horror movie.

instead, since I will be talking about every single horror movie. And I think that:

- **movie** is countable noun and
- **horror** functions as an adjectival or attributive noun here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't enjoy watching horror movies.
 is correct..
 But we can also use the indefinite  article **a** in the sense of any, to single out an individual as the representative of a class

> e.g a boy should obey his parents.

Therefore
I don't enjoy watching a horror movie.
 is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you say:

> I don't enjoy watching horror movies.

you speak in general, about (almost) all horror movies, AND about all times when you want to watch a movie.

---

If you say:

> I don't enjoy watching a horror movie.

it **can** change the meaning to: now I do not want to watch a horror movie, but in the future maybe I will enjoy watching one.

Overall, the meaning of the two sentences is quite similar, and the first form is preferred.

---

If you want to make a *clear* statement for just one instance, you can say:

> I don't feel like watching a horror movie (now / today / ...).